# Elisp code to make a specific target

Tags: emacs, build, makefile, elisp

I would love to teach emacs how to build a specific target. 
What is the non-interactive equivalent of "make foo"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(compile "make foo")`

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the answer as "accepted" (by clicking on the big green tick mark) then.